# Combine speed of several access points

Tags: linux, bash, network-programming

I would like to combine the speed of 2 (or more) access points into 1. (+ 3G USB phone too)

I have 3 different interfaces : `wlan0`, `wlan1` and `usb1`. (they can all be connected to a separate internet access.)

Comment: You can't "combine" the speed of multiple interfaces. You can however send out different messages through different interfaces, even if all messages have the same destination (if it's possible with available routing etc.)

Comment: I don't see how it's "impossible". If two computers are connected to 2 different connections and each of them download 50% of a file. At the same time, they can send the data to a third computer on the LAN. What is the problem with that idea ? (can't virtualize this ?)

Comment: That's what I meant by sending different messages over each interface. If, for example, you're sending a file, you can send half of it over one interface and the other half over the other interface. You don't "combine" the speed, but the measured time to send the file may be halved because each interface is only sending half the file.

Comment: My question remain, i'm not sure how to virtualize this. And i'm a little surprised i can't find an easy answer anywhere.

Comment: Search for "link aggregation".

Comment: thx ! i'm now looking into https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding